# How to order by a string of numbers separates by dot

Tags: postgresql

I have a query for run over the tree structure, using a CTE way.
The problem is that I use one column called `camino` for `ORDER BY` clause. This column is get like that:

```
---
UNION ALL
SELECT rel.codpadre, rel.codhijo, rel.canpres, depth+1, camino || ''.'' || CAST(rel.posicion AS text) , rel.posicion
FROM ---
```

This one :

`camino || ''.'' || CAST(rel.posicion AS text`

gives me a column like that:

```
0.0.1
0.0.10
0.0.1.0
0.0.1.0.0
0.0.10.0
0.0.1.0.1
0.0.10.1
0.0.2
.......
```

I need to order by those column, but considering 10 after 9, no after 1.

Comment: Please include the full query.  Is the maximum number of path components known?

Comment: The query is very large, and I think that it could hide the important part. Anyway, it has been answered and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to an array of integers:

```
order by string_to_array(camino, '.')::int[]
```

or

```
order by string_to_array(concat_ws('.', camino, posicion), '.')::int[]
```

Comment: Thank you. The first version is that I was looking for.